# Python __init__ and classmethod, do they have to have the same number of args?

Tags: python, oop, constructor, arguments, class-method

So classmethods can be used as an alternative "constructor" in python, they are bound to the class and not to an instance, pretty clear so far. But my question is, if it is mandatory to have the same number of arguments in the returned instance of the class method as in the `__init__`. More exactly :

```py
    class MyClass(object):
      def __init__(self,name):
         self.name=name

      @classmethod
      def alternative_init(cls,name,surname):
          return cls(name,surname)
```

And if I try to create an instance `Myclass("alex")` works fine, but if I try to create an instance `Myclass.alternative_init("alex","james")` I have a `TypeError` , because I pass to many arguments, and init take only 2 . Am I missing something?

Comment: `cls(name,surname)` *calls* `__init__`.

Comment: Thanks , makes sense now .

Comment: No they don't have to have the same number of args, you can make `alternative_init()` do whatever its code says to do. But what is `Myclass.alternative_init("alex","james")` supposed to give? One instance containing a list of names? Two instances ? (yield'ed from a generator? as a list?) or what?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`__init__` only takes one parameter, the name. Thus, you can pass either `name` or `surname` to `cls`, but not both. However, you can create a class instance in `classmethod`, and add an additional paramter:

```
class MyClass(object):
  def __init__(self,name):
    self.name=name
  def __setattr__(self, name, val):
     self.__dict__[name] = val
  @classmethod
  def alternative_init(cls,name,surname):
    v = cls(name)
    v.surname = surname
    return v
```

Comment: As far as I understand, since you returns v, your `alternative_init` method is more of an `alternative_new`

Answer (score 2):

You could do what you want like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name

    @classmethod
    def alternative_init(cls,name,surname):
        new_instance = cls(name)
        new_instance.surname = surname
        return new_instance

a = MyClass.alternative_init('Bob', 'Spongy')
print(a.name, a.surname)
# Bob Spongy
```

Comment: Ok, so basically I can create an instance inside the classmethod and then add attribute to that instance. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: That's it, you can. But for this particular case, it would be better to have a default argument `surname` in `__init__`, because the `surname` attribute of your instance would be left undefined if you called `__init__`

Answer (score 2):

Because `Myclass.alternative_init("alex","james")` calls the cls(name, surname) which same as `MyClass(name,surname)` which also same as `__init__(self,name,surname)` but your `__init__` function don't have `surname` parameter. You can make `surname` optional by `__init__(self,name,surname=None)`

```
class MyClass(object):
  def __init__(self,name,surname=None):
     self.name=name
     self.surname=surname

  @classmethod
  def alternative_init(cls,name,surname):
      return cls(name,surname)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python, the first argument Passed to a method is always the object itself. 
If you call now your method with a name, you will get self as first parameter and the name as second.

When you call now the **init** method from inside of your classmethod, python has no idea what it should do with the surname.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name

    @classmethod
    def alternative_init(cls,name,surname):
        return cls(name)


a = MyClass("alex")
MyClass.alternative_init("alex","james")
```

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.